# How can I format (line up) c# code in Visual Studio?

Tags: format

Please let me know if it's possible to get Visual Studio 2019 for c# to format the way I'd like it to.  I would like to line up my c# code to make it easier for me to read.

This is how Visual Studio 2019 is formatting the code:

```
            myArray[i] = "abcd";
            anotherArray[i] = "efg";
            yourArray[i] = "fun";

            if (maxLenMyArray < myArray[i].Length) maxLenMyArray = myArray[i].Length;
            if (maxLenAnnotherArray < myAnotherArray[i].Length) maxLenAnotherArray = myAnotherArray[i].Length;
            if (maxLenYourArray < myYourArray[i].Length) maxLenYourArray = myYourArray[i].Length;
```

This is how I want it to format the code:

```
            myArray[i]       = "abcd";
            anotherArray[i]  = "efg";
            yourArray[i]     = "fun";

            if (maxLenMyArray       < myArray[i].Length)        maxLenMyArray      = myArray[i].Length;
            if (maxLenAnnotherArray < myAnotherArray[i].Length) maxLenAnotherArray = myAnotherArray[i].Length;
            if (maxLenYourArray     < myYourArray[i].Length)    maxLenYourArray    = myYourArray[i].Length;
```

Or at times I may want to format it like this:

```
                myArray      [i] = "abcd";
                anotherArray [i] = "efg";
                yourArray    [i] = "fun";

                if (maxLenMyArray       < myArray       [i].Length) maxLenMyArray      = myArray 
  [i].Length;
                if (maxLenAnnotherArray < myAnotherArray[i].Length) maxLenAnotherArray = myAnotherArray 
  [i].Length;
                if (maxLenYourArray     < myYourArray   [i].Length) maxLenYourArray    = myYourArray 
  [i].Length;
```